# Naive Bayes Algorithm with floating weights or zero weights

Tags: probability, machine-learning, naive-bayes

What happens on those cases on Naive Bayes Algorithm :

1.one of the weights are zero ? 2.one of the weights are float?

I am asking because i am trying to use Naive Bayes  to develop small application ,where some of the return values of the attributes are zero or floats

should I normalize the floats weights to integer ,should i remove the zero weight or it didn’t affect the result ?

Comment: Can you specify what the Naive Bayes Algorithm does? Also I have no idea what 'Algorithm::NaiveBayes' is.

Comment: it used for classification my question what happens from the mathmatical point when the weight is zero , does in this case the result will be always zero?,and what happens if the wieghts are floats ?